# running python+flask on heroku, without gunicorn

Tags: python, heroku, flask

Locally I have hello.py like this (first code)

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Then locally I run

```
python hello.py
```

and this works. It listens on port 80 for HTTP connection, and returns 'Hello World!'.

Now, on heroku, the example they give you is (second code)

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

(notice app.run is missing) and they tell you to use a Profile with gunicorn:

```
web: gunicorn hello:app
```

This works on heroku.

Now, my question is the following. Because this is part of something much bigger which I have thought out to run as in first code (WITH run.app), I would like to have THAT running on heroku. I would like to be able to run first code on heroku, but it doesn't work. How do I do that?

Comment: Found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714205/deploying-flask-app-to-heroku?answertab=oldest#tab-top