# Deploying Flask app to Heroku stuck in restarting loop

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have a simple Flask app that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku, but I'm facing an Application Error and the logs seem to indicate that the app is stuck in some sort of restarting loop. I think there is a problem with my Procfile or run.py but I can't figure out what.
Here are the Heroku logs:

```
2014-07-13T03:02:24.579923+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
2014-07-13T03:02:24.580216+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Restarting with reloader
2014-07-13T03:02:29.941158+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/mechanize_boilerplate.py:13: UserWarning: gzip transfer encoding is experimental!
2014-07-13T03:02:29.941168+00:00 app[web.1]:   br.set_handle_gzip(True)
2014-07-13T03:02:29.955461+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
2014-07-13T03:02:29.955738+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Restarting with reloader
2014-07-13T03:02:35.300236+00:00 app[web.1]:   br.set_handle_gzip(True)
2014-07-13T03:02:35.300231+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/mechanize_boilerplate.py:13: UserWarning: gzip transfer encoding is experimental!
2014-07-13T03:02:35.314821+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
2014-07-13T03:02:35.315107+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Restarting with reloader
...
```

## Here is my current project structure:

```
/myapplication
    Procfile
    run.py
    requirements.txt
    /app
        __init__.py
        views.py
        mechanize_boilerplate.py
        /static
        /templates
```

## Here is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn run:app
```

## Here is run.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

## Here is **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

From there views.py runs and is pretty classic.
I've seen a few [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416699/heroku-flask-deploy-a-modular-app-from-tutorial-not-working-foreman-start-w?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260338/deploying-flask-with-heroku) and tried playing with my Procfile but couldn't get it work, all I managed to do was crashing the app.
Any suggestions?

Comment: what happens when you run the app locally?

Comment: Everything works fine... I had to add the Procfile for Heroku which makes me suspect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `run.py` runs your application when gunicorn imports it. You only want that to happen when you execute it.

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That didn't work immediately but I changed my `run.py` to:
 `#!flask/bin/python
 from app import app

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()`

And that fixed it!

Comment: Sorry, yeah, that's what I mean. I copied the code from the wrong file above. I'll fix the answer to make it cleared to people in the future.