# Python Flask heroku application error

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku, flask

So I do have a flask app, I can run it in my computer locally and deployed it to heroku successfully but when I do `heroku open` the site keeps on saying Application Error.

This is in my app.py:

```
import random
import os

from flask import Flask
from gen_histogram import histogram
from sample import generate_probability, generate_word

app = Flask(__name__)

dict_histogram = histogram('tom_sawyer.txt')

tes_list = ["one", "fish", "two", "fish", "red", "fish", "blue", "fish"]


def try_random():
   return random.choice(tes_list)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return try_random()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
   app.run(debug=True, port=port)
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Notes:

> I have everything setup including virtualenv and requirements.txt

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: @DanielRoseman -----> Python app detected
     $ pip install -r requirements.txt
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 38.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v7
       https://tweetkaka.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

Comment: @AdemÖztaş Basically no error output in the terminal, but when I go the site it keeps on saying Application error, "your application cannot be served"

Comment: did you look at the log? you can check like this `heroku logs -t `

Comment: @AdemÖztaş "No web processes running"

Comment: Can you try changing this line `app.run(debug=True, port=port)` to `app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)`. That might work.

Comment: @hassan I did that, no good sign.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think a likely possibility is that that gunicorn is not using the correct port. Heroku assigns a port for the application. I'm not entirely sure if that port gets assigned randomly or if it has a default. But if this is what is causing the problem, changing the `Procfile` to this should fix it:

```
web: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app
```

This way catches whatever port assignment Heroku does. Or if you choose to set an environment variable for `PORT` it will also use that. gunicorn defaults to port 8000, so setting the `PORT` environment variable to 8000 on Heroku should also work.

- Related: [Deploying Flask app to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714205)

I'm pretty sure that the `app.run` does not effect the gunicorn server in any way. I think that gunicorn just finds the application instance in the module specified by `app:app` (`module:appinstance`), and loads the views.

- ref: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#bind

Answer (score 3):

I created a file called `Procfile` in my root folder containing

```
web: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app
```

Im my `app.py`, i have

```
import os
...
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
...
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

Heroku dyno will set it's own PORT env and the app will use that rather than the default 5000 i use locally.

Working example at https://github.com/Sean-Bradley/Seans-Python3-Flask-Rest-Boilerplate