# Heroku Flask app crashes before it even starts

Tags: flask, heroku

I get this error in my logs --tail

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tsuyo-workout.herokuapp.com request_id=069bdbc7-cdb1-4d4e-8cc2-ec8dc55890f5 fwd="184.189.121.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

At first I had my port set to 5000 as I was developing locally. I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714205/deploying-flask-app-to-heroku) to fix the h10 error. I still have the same error.

I fixed some other errors before this and they were:

Not having a Procfile. I added one.

**Procfile**:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

I fixed up my requirements.txt. I added gunicorn.

**requirments.txt**

```
click==8.0.3
Flask==2.0.2
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
Werkzeug==2.0.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

I think the only relevant info in my app.py is this. Let me know if you need more:

**app.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
port = int(os.getenv('PORT'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=port)
```

I have a database in this app. Could it be the fact that I have a database?

Some more lines of errors per request.

```
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695436+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695436+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695437+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695437+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695437+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695437+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695438+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695438+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695439+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695439+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695439+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695440+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695440+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695440+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695440+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695441+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695441+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695441+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695441+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695442+00:00 app[web.1]: from helper import message, get_db_connection, default, login_required
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695442+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/helper.py", line 2, in <module>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695442+00:00 app[web.1]: from turtle import clear
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695443+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695443+00:00 app[web.1]: import tkinter as TK
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695443+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695444+00:00 app[web.1]: import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695444+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
2022-07-06T20:50:53.695559+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-06 20:50:53 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696450+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-06 20:50:53 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696451+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696451+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696452+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696452+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696452+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696453+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696453+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696454+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696454+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696454+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696454+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696455+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696455+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696455+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696455+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696456+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696456+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696457+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696457+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696457+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696458+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696458+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696458+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696459+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696459+00:00 app[web.1]: from helper import message, get_db_connection, default, login_required
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696459+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/helper.py", line 2, in <module>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696460+00:00 app[web.1]: from turtle import clear
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696462+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696462+00:00 app[web.1]: import tkinter as TK
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696463+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696463+00:00 app[web.1]: import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696463+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
2022-07-06T20:50:53.696580+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-07-06 20:50:53 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.745546+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-06T20:50:53.745553+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2022-07-06T20:50:53.745765+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.745775+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
2022-07-06T20:50:53.745917+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.745927+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746025+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746033+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746179+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746222+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746223+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746223+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746223+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746230+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746232+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746304+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746306+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746383+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746398+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746488+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746489+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746561+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746563+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746654+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746656+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746772+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746773+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 388, in stop
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746893+00:00 app[web.1]: limit = time.time() + self.cfg.graceful_timeout
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746894+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746969+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.settings[name].get()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.746971+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2022-07-06T20:50:53.747058+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2022-07-06T20:50:53.747068+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2022-07-06T20:50:53.747213+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2022-07-06T20:50:53.747235+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2022-07-06T20:50:53.882989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-06T20:50:53.927947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-07-06T21:18:19.470130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tsuyo-workout.herokuapp.com request_id=767ea937-4ad8-46f4-ad68-a8fa68f8c15b fwd="184.189.121.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: What do the logs say right before that line? We need more context.

Comment: That's a _bit_ more context, and does help, but it doesn't look like a full traceback. Please include all contiguous lines that appear to be part of this error.

Comment: Are you able to run `gunicorn app:app` locally?

Comment: I have not run the `gunicorn app:app` locally. I will start learning how to do that right now.

Comment: ...and, there it is: you are importing `turtle` / `tkinter` in `helper.py`. That won't be available on Heroku and you almost certainly don't need it anyway. Your text editor probably "helpfully" added an import it thought you needed. Please see the marked duplicates.

Comment: There you go! If @Chris's solution works, I will remove my answer. Meanwhile, keeping it posted in case you need to follow it.

Comment: @Chris That's it! It works. I have switch from Pythonanywhere to gcloud to heroku. All because I couldn't get this to work and it was all due to a simple import that should have never been there. So frustrating but so satisfying to get it online right now.

Comment: @Funlamb, welcome to the world of software development :-). That frustration / elation will never entirely go away.